# BigQuery | Assigning numbers to rows based on running sum

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a table that lists my volunteers and a column for the number of postcards they've decided to write. I'm trying to return a row that creates a row assigning each volunteer to a postcard based on how many the requested.

For example, if volunteer A requested 3 postcards, volunteer B, 1 postcard, and volunteer C requested 2 postcards, then I'd want my query to return something like this:

| rowNumber | volunteer | postcardsAssigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Volunteer A | 1 |
| 2 | Volunteer A | 2 |
| 3 | Volunteer A | 3 |
| 4 | Volunteer B | 4 |
| 5 | Volunteer C | 5 |
| 6 | Volunteer C | 6 |

Attached a picture below that shows what my current query results in and what I'm trying to get it to look like.

```
With postcards_vols as (SELECT What_s_your_name_ as Name
, What_s_your_email_ as Email
, What_s_your_phone_number_ as Phonenumber 
, Mailing_Street_Address as StreetAddress
, Mailing_City as City
, Mailing_Zip_code as Zip 
, Mailing_State as State
, How_many_cards_would_you_like_us_to_send_ as Postcards_Requested
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS Request_Number 
, Submitted_At as date_requested 
FROM volunteer_program.postcard_volunteers)

SELECT * 
, SUM (Postcards_requested) OVER (PARTITION BY request_number, date_requested ORDER BY date_requested DESC) AS addresses_assigned,
FROM 
postcards_vols

[Current Query Output and Sample Desired Query Output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGssK.png

* Names and address shown in the picture are fictitious
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the extra rows you want using arrays and then unnesting:

```
select pv.*, num,
       row_number() over (order by volunteer, num) as postcardsassigned
from `postcards_vols` pv cross join 
     unnest(generate_array(1, pv.request_number)) num;
```

`num` is an enumeration *within* each volunteer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I hadn't used a cross join in a minute.
This seemed to do the trick.

```
with postcards_vols as (SELECT What_s_your_name_  as Name
, What_s_your_email_ as Email
, What_s_your_phone_number_ as Phonenumber 
, Mailing_Street_Address as StreetAddress
, Mailing_City as City
, Mailing_Zip_code as Zip 
, Mailing_State as State
, How_many_cards_would_you_like_us_to_send_ as Postcards_Requested
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS Request_Number 
, Submitted_At as date_requested 
FROM `noble-hangar-313121.volunteer_program.postcard_volunteers`),

distribution AS (
SELECT pv.*, num,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name, num) AS postcardsassigned
FROM `postcards_vols` pv CROSS JOIN
     unnest(generate_array(1, pv.Postcards_Requested)) num
     )
     
 SELECT request_number as packet_number
, Name as volunteer_name
, Email as volunteer_email
, Phonenumber as volunteer_phone
, StreetAddress as volunteer_streetAddress
, City as volunteer_city
, Zip as volunteer_zip
, State as volunteer_state
, Address as postcard_address
, city_State as postcard_citystate
, zipcode as postcard_zipcode 


 FROM
 distribution d
 LEFT JOIN 
 field_report.postcard_address_distribution
 ON number = postcardsassigned

     GROUP BY request_number, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11
     ORDER BY packet_number
```